# Convert std string to ascii char and send through the serial port c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, serial-port

I'm quite new to c++ and this is my problem:
I have a std::string and I want to convert each character to its Ascii symbol, put them into a unsigned char buffer and send all through the serial port. I know it can't be so clear so I 'll give an example:

```
std::string stringaStd = "010203";
```

I would like to send through the serial port the sequence:

```
'0' '1' '0' '2' '0' '3'
```

that should be equivalent to:

```
0x30 0x31 0x30 0x32 0x30 0x33
```

Hence, the chars of stringaStd have to be converted to Ascii and after that sent through the serial port. 
Any idea for how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is 7-bit characters. There are extensions (ANSI character set, CP-1252, whatever) with 8 bits but pure ASCII does not utilize the most significant bit. Network transmission might make use of it as a parity flag for error detection/correction but I am drifting away from the main topic.

A `char` is by standard definition at least 8 bits wide, i.e., it is definitely capable of holding an ASCII character.

Retrieve single `char`s from the string using `std::string::operator[]` like in

```
stringaStd[x]
```

and, to obtain only the ASCII-relevant part, AND it with `0x7f`:

```
stringaStd[x] & 0x7f
```

Usually, the unused bits in a `char` when representing an ASCII character are cleared but I don't think this is standardized anywhere.

This whole process can be mangled into a loop. Range checking can be performed using exceptions (`std::string::at`), C-string null terminators (`std::string::c_str` or, since C++11, also `std::string::data`), or iterators (range-based `for`-loop).
In addition, use the API provided to interact with the appropriate serial port and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler uses ASCII to encode character strings (which it almost certainly does; I mention this only for completeness) then the characters in a `std::string` object are already ASCII. There is no conversion needed. The character value `'0'`, treated as a number, has the value `0x30`. Try it:

```
char ch = '0';
std::cout << ch << ' ' << (int)ch << '\n';
```

To write those ASCII values one at a time to a port, just do it:

```
std::string text("012345");
for (int i = 0 ;i < text.size(); ++i)
    send_to_port(text[i]);
```

If you need an intermediate buffer, again, just do it:

```
unsigned char buf[80];
assert(text.size() <= 80);
std::copy(text.begin(), text.end(), buf);
```

Masking `char` values with `0x7f` is wrong. If the string somehow has non-ASCII values (i.e., 8-bit values with the high bit set), masking will clear the high bit, producing a value in the range for valid ASCII characters, but the value won't represent anything meaningful.

Comment: Thanks Pete! And if I want to send characters that are not in range [0-9, A-F], for example STX (0x02) or ETX (0x03), how should I treat and send them accordingly with your example code?